# Start VS Code debug target in sudo mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My code plays around several HCI switches using BlueZ and requires it be started in sudo mode.

However, when debugging using VS Code, I am unable to launch it using sudo. Is there a way to accomplish it? Otherwise certain HCI calls to lower layers will fail.

Answer (score -3):

If this is a Python script, you can create a Python debug configuration and then set the [`sudo`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_sudo) option to `true`:

> When set to `true` and used with `"console": "externalTerminal"`, allows for debugging apps that require elevation. Using an external console is necessary to capture the password.

```json
{
    "name": "run-python-script-with-sudo",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "program": "/path/to/script.py",
    "console": "externalTerminal",
    "sudo": true
}
```

Running that debug configuration will launch an external console where you will need to input the `sudo` password, and then the script is run with root permissions.